# Ruby on Rails. Devise. Registration form in yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I application.html.erb I add `<%= yield %>`. I want to show registration page (/users/sign_up) with header and footer in application.html.erb. As I understand contant from /device/registration/new.html.erb must contain in yield, but I get registration page withot templates(header and footer).

How I could show registration form in yiled?

I use RoR 3.2.12. Sorry for my English. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the registration page without the layout, then chances are you have a :layout => false triggered somewhere upstream.